# cast a list for example (list a) to an empy list for example (list b) and when i only change first list (a) not (b) ,both (a) and (b) change together

Tags: python, python-3.x

hello guys i have a question about ""python"" please help me
I have 2 list for example a and b
when I cast list a to b
and then I change elements of list b
both list changing
but I want not change list a(prime list) change at all

```
code is here in python:
a = [4,7]
b = []
b = a
b[1] = 0
print(a)
#####
output is:
[4, 0]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Rd9.jpg)

Comment: In your code, `b = []` has no lasting effect. `b = a` overrides the earlier assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This is an optimization issue as python does not create a new memory location for b if `b=a`. So essentially they are the same object and reside at the same location. To create a copy of a and store it in b, you can `b = a[:]` or `b = a.copy()`.